# .net core 3.1 with Npgsql EF Core - Can't write CLR type enum with handler type Int32Handler

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I got this error then I'm trying to call this query with OData:

```
return _unitOfWork
   .SinglePaymentRepository
   .GetAllQueryable()
   .Where(x => x.PaymentType == (int)singlePaymentType)
   .ProjectTo<SinglePaymentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

> System.InvalidCastException: Can't write CLR type
>   Project.Services.Enums.SinglePaymentType with handler type
>   Int32Handler

But if I just do the casting before like this:

```
var type = (int)singlePaymentType;
return _unitOfWork
   .SinglePaymentRepository
   .GetAllQueryable()
   .Where(x => x.PaymentType == type)
   .ProjectTo<SinglePaymentDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

`SinglePaymentType` is an enum of course. In .NET Core 2.2 version everything worked.

Comment: You seem to be using something besides EF Core - what are GetAllQueryable and ProjectTo? In any case, a minimal sample of casting an enum to an int in a Where clause works for me on pure EF Core 3.1.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I found that it only fails where an enum parameter is passed to the function as an argument - try this way and look that is would fail with Npgsql, that is very strange. It works for example on SQL Server and also if the enum variable is created inside the function. I found an issue on github about this - https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/489
Here this particular case is mentioned - https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/489#issuecomment-401563522